# Jumping between activities without losing data

Tags: android, location, android-activity

In my app there are 5 Activities and flow is `A >> B >> C >> D >> E >> F`.

**B** is TextBox where user enter details and i am saving the detail using static variable method.

**D** is locationActivity and in this also i am saving data using static variable method.

**E** is the summary screen having textView to display results from all the activities.

**F** is final view which displays all the data with some animation.

Now the problem is if in summary screen user find's that he has entered his details Wrong and wants to edit it then how he will do that without losing data obtained from location activity.

Is there is a way other than `E >> B` then `B >> E`,because I don't want to put an extra button in activity B and i am also not sure will the user get actual data from location activity after he edits his details in B.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityE.this, ActivityB.class); 
    finish();
    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

in activity E and use `intent.putExtra()` to pass any variable from E to B

So when u press the back button of your device u should go to activity B.

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) is tutorial

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution that comes to mind is to simply pass along data with [`putExtra()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) between your activities. This should require little work to your existing code.

Nice tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) (see 1.4)

Answer (score 0):

Either pass the information around the activities or store it in the Application object to be used everywhere.